# How do I uninstall/remove XRCed?

Tags: uninstall

I've been trying to remove this "package" (XRCed), which I have no idea how I got installed in the first place.

It seems it has something to do with this: http://manned.org/xrced/cbeff1fd

The thing is I cannot find it in the Ubuntu Software Center, and going `sudo apt-get remove XRCed` does nothing.  Nonetheless, if I search for it in the `super` button I get the application, and if I click it, it actually runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an xrced file with path `/usr/bin/xrced` that is installed by the python-wxtools package, as the link in your question suggests. Uninstalling python-wxtools will remove xcred.

```
sudo apt-get remove python-wxtools
```

Comment: I do want to keep the wxWidgets and wxPython packages.  Does removing python-wxtools has some impact on them?

Comment: python-wxtools is described as a wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (wxPython common files), so removing python-wxtools would probably have some impact on the wxWidgets and wxPython packages. Alternatively you could try renaming xrced to xrced.backup and then test if that breaks anything.